# Avoid dashed border around clicked link

Tags: html, css

I have a link (in fact a dropdown menu link) when clicked I have a dashed border around this link.

How can I avoid this behaviour?

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: If you must remove the focus outline, please do it in accordance with the advice here: http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/04/how-to-remove-css-outlines-in-an-accessible-manner/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the CSS `:focus` and `:active` specifiers:

```
.yourclass:focus, .yourclass:active {
    outline: 0; /*make sure no outline appears*/
}
```

And a little working demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/Y2R7u/).

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

As an addendum to Chris's, answer (can't comment yet)

Make sure to also include

```
.yourclass:focus { outline: 0; }
```

to keep the outline from showing up on some corner cases where the focus remains on an element.